# Can Faerie characters learn Faerie Magic?

Tags: ars-magica-5

Realm Of Power:Faerie describes two new magic methods. Faerie rites and Faerie bargaining. Are these magic methods exclusive to magi or can they be used by faerie PCs through the usage of Focus Power virtue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Faerie PC is not as simple a term as you may think

In *Houses of Hermes: Mystery Cults*, p. 93, is detailed the Merinita Mystery of *Becoming*, whereby a Hermetic Maga can become a Faerie. As such, the methods you mentioned are definitely not exclusive to human Magi, but are also accessible to (some) Faerie PCs.

However, assuming your question relates to characters created as Faerie characters without a history of being a Hermetic Maga...

### Focus Power

I'll start off by quoting the first sentence of the introductory text for Focus Powers:

> Focus powers can have broad application, and should be discussed with the Troupe when selected.

These are supposed to be somewhat spontaneous applications of a Faerie's Faerie nature, allowing it a broader range of options than the typical Faerie Power. Smithying is a good example:

> Duplicates any non-Ritual Creo, Muto, Rego, or Perdo spell pertaining to the Terram Form[,] limited by the motif of the faerie.

This would allow a Faerie Smith...yer? to extract metal from ore as well as shape the metal itself, but probably not raise a giant stone tower in spite of *Conjuring the Mystic Tower* being Creo Terram, since it in most situations would not adhere to the motif of a Faerie Smith...yer.

### Faerie Rites

In essence, these are in and of themselves tied to a Sympathy, which in many ways are the same thing as the motif needed by the Smithyer above. I would describe these as the same thing as Focus Powers, only accessible to human (hedge) wizards through their Gift.

### Faerie Bargaining

This entire method revolves around contacting a Faerie and convincing them to aid you in one way or another. The method in specific is a wizardly one, using the Gift to enforce their will onto the fabric of reality.

##### However...

I would always allow a Faerie following their own tale to contact another Faerie and seek their assistance, which for most Faeries would involve a gift, a task or a concession.

### TL; DR: No.

Comment: I would like to state that my interpretation of the Becoming is that it gradually binds you to a faerie and when you finish the final aspect instead of turning you into a Faerie it kills you and replaces you with the faerie you were bound to.

Comment: @MaikoChikyu Hush, do not clue the mortals in, would you have them no longer pursue their own demise in furtherance of the plans of the Unseelie court?